# How to stream RTSP on the web?

Tags: web, video, safari, mobile-safari, rtsp

We generate RTSP stream (MP4 with ACC codec for audio) on our server and we need to send it to web app and play it.

We could send it via websocket and play it with media extensions but they are not supported on iOS.

We could also use WebRTC with media channel but that supports only Opus audio codec and we cannot afford transcoding from ACC to Opus.

Do you have any idea how can we play RTSP data on iOS devices?

EDIT: we aim for low latency playback (<1s) HSL has latency 5s+

Answer (score 1):

you need to encode/package your stream in HLS on your server to send it to iOS clients. Try to look into FFMPEG streaming guides where the input is your RTSP stream and output is HLS. iOS really only plays HLS.

Comment: Forgot to mention. We know about HSL but it is unusable with its 5s+ latency

Comment: You will have to change your original audio encoding. Your only option for <1s latency is WebRTC. So you must have Opus or G.711 audio encoding. Most systems, like RTSP cameras, encode G.711 natively, so try to see if you can go wiht G.711